# Are certain intuitions more valid than other kinds of intuitions?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

Suppose I can't think of any good reason to doubt that the external world is "real". I.e. when I touch the cup in front of me, I recognize that even though it could be an illusion, I instinctively/intuitively think it's real. Is this belief based on intuition?

Suppose now that I'm studying the similarity relation. I realize that an object A can be similar to object B depending on context. There seems to be different ways to define similarity, and even when one way is picked, such as measuring how many properties are shared between objects, it begs the question of which properties to look at and how many there are or could be known.

Yet, intuitively, when I see a water bottle, I will think of it as immediately more similar to a cup than say a pillow. This is because there are certain properties between the cup and bottle that seem more intuitively obvious/important that are shared between them than there are between a cup and a pillow. And yet, this kind of intuition seems interally to differ from the intuition that tells me reality might be real. Since the very notion of similariy seems subjective.

Are these different or the same kinds of intuition? Is one more valid than the other?

Comment: *Intuition* can be a result of experience or simply a figment of imagination.

Comment: See ["Experimental Philosophy"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/experimental-philosophy/) (SEP).